# Returning a GET view after a POST view Fails ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, http-post

I have a View in MVC called Action, which accepts and ID as parameter. I also have another view called Action, but it is marked as HTTPPOST.

The POST version of Action can fail programatically. When it fails, I want to add a ModelError, and then Redirect to the GET version of Action, whilst I provide the ID .

In short => I want to transfer to a GET view from a POST view, and pass parameters. Something along the lines of

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Could not verify token");
return RedirectToAction("Action", "ExpiredAccounts" new { aid = myId });
```

Where Action is the View, ExpiredAccounts is the Controller and AID is the Account ID. This of course does not work since you can add a model error to a view, not redirecting

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Why not just return the model errors on the POST if it fails?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'd better return the same view in this case instead of redirecting:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Could not verify token");
var model = repository.Get(myId);
return View(model);
```

The correct flow of the [`Redirect-After-Post`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern is the following:

1. GET request -> some form is displayed
2. POST request -> the form is submitted to the server. Two possible cases here:

   - Validation succeeds => Redirect.
   - Validation fails => redisplay the same view so that the user can fix the errors

If you want to violate this best practice you could always send the error message as query string parameter when redirecting:

```
return RedirectToAction(
    "Action", 
    "ExpiredAccounts" 
    new { aid = myId, error = "Could not verify token" }
);
```

and then in side the target action verify whether this parameter has been supplied and add an error to the modelstate:

```
public ActionResult Action(int myId, string error)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Allright - I did something along the lines Darin Dimitrov did. The issue was that I had quite a lot of code in the GET request. Therefore, I placed the Get request into a private method, and I call it from the GET method, and when the POST fails.